# solve for x(t) under integral

Tags: convolution, integral-equations

the following integral equation must be solved for x(t).
$$x(t) + \mu(t) \frac{1}{T} \int_{T}x(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau = y(t)$$

where $y(t)$, $\mu(t)$, and $h(t)$ are all known functions. All functions are periodic with period $T$. $y(t)$ and $mu(t)$ are rectangular-shaped while $h(t)$ is something complicated.

is there an analytic solution which gives the answer with great precision? I once attempted to solve with fourier series, and since I could use only a few number of harmonics, the solution was not perfectly precise.

if there is a solution using laplace transform in piecewise mode, or other analytic methods, would be appreciated.

Comment: The factor $\mu(t)$ is embarrassing. Without it, you could solve by the Laplace transform.

Comment: What is regularity of your function ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust  yes thansks I knew, I've already have solved for constant $\mu$ using fourier series, too easy, but I was wondering if say another integral transform could be used to solve this one.

Comment: @EDX thanks for reply, $\mu(t)$ and $y(y)$ are rectangular-shape functions so having finite number of discontinuities per one period. if I'm correct by the definition of regularity of functions.

Comment: @JJacquelin it's (integral over a period) at an arbitrary interval but the length of the interval must be T. the integral is a circular convolution. thanks for reply.

Comment: If $\mu$ is piecewise constant, you can solve for every interval by Laplace.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. I doubt it is correct, can you solve an example?

Comment: $X+\dfrac \mu TXH=Y$ and $X=\dfrac Y{1+\dfrac\mu TH}$. Can you disprove that ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust. since laplace transform is defined on $[0,\infty]$, then $\mu$ transform would not be the same. I think your solution is valid only when $\mu$ and $y$ is constant for all times. furthermore while we are taking laplace of the integral we assume for one period and not only that interval for which $\mu=constant$. that's why I think we are not allowed to do so.

Comment: @HoseinJavanmardi: if your equation is causal (and it is), there is no problem assuming a plain constant function and solving by Laplace. Then solve with new initial conditions at the next interval. But I don't think you want to try this.

Comment: @YvesDaoust you're right, that initial condition for next interval idea I had a thought about that, like a switching function, but the integral I could not figure out. thank you I must try it.